# Sql Server - How do I get JSON nested value in my SQL Select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Environment**: SQL Server 2014 and above

How do I access the email value in my JSON value with my SELECT statement?

```
select JSON_VALUE('[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}]', '$.email') as test
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`?

Comment: No, is that native to SQL Server?

Comment: Yes [OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You can't do that with 2014 version. JSON support was introduced in 2016.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed 2014 (was reading the tags instead) and as you had `JSON_VALUE` (also added in 2016) I *assumed* you had 2016+.

Comment: On that basis, honestly, you're better off using something else other than SQL Server to parse JSON (in my opinion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json support was only introduced in SQL Server 2016 - so with any prior version you would need to either use string manipulation code or simply parse the json outside of SQL Server (maybe using a CLR function)

For 2016 version or higher, you can use `JSON_VALUE` like this:

```
declare @json as varchar(100) = '[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}]';

select JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].data.email') as test
```

For older versions - you might be able to get away with this, but if your json value does not contain an `email` property, you will get unexpected results:

```
select substring(string, start, charindex('"', string, start+1) - start) as test
from (
    select @json as string, charindex('"email":"', @json) + 9 as start
) s
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5350465bb747a9665b94706d24feac63)

Comment: What if there were more than one object in the JSON, how do you display all of them in table format?

Comment: For 2014 version you either handle the json outside SQL Server, or use Alan Burstein or Shnugo's answer. Mine is just a simple workaround. For 2016 or higher you use `OPENJSON` with a `with` clause.

Answer (score 4):

Another way. [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) is great for stuff like this.

**Extract a single Email value:**

```
DECLARE @json as varchar(200) = '[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}]';

SELECT f.Item
FROM   dbo.patternsplitCM(@json,'[a-z0-9@.]') AS f
WHERE  f.item LIKE '%[a-z]%@%.%[a-z]%'; -- Simple Email Check Pattern
```

**Extracting all Email Addresses (if/when there are more):**

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(200) = '[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"},{"email2":"test2@email.net"}},{"data":{"MoreEmail":"test3@email.555whatever"}}]';

SELECT f.Item
FROM   dbo.patternsplitCM(@json,'[a-z0-9@.]') AS f
WHERE  f.item LIKE '%[a-z]%@%.%[a-z]%'; -- Simple Email Check Pattern
```

**Returns:**

```
Item
--------------------------
test@email.com
test2@email.net
test3@email.555whatever
```

Or... the get only the first Email address that appears:

```
SELECT TOP (1) f.Item
FROM     dbo.patternsplitCM(@json,'[a-z0-9@.]') AS f
WHERE    f.item LIKE '%[a-z]%@%.%[a-z]%' -- Simple Email Check Pattern
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.ItemNumber)
```

Nasty fast, super-simple. No cursors, loops or other bad stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in two ways:
First, if your JSON data is between `[ ]` like in your question:

```
select JSON_VALUE('[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}]','$[0].data.email' ) as test
```

And if your JSON data is not between `[ ]`:

```
select JSON_VALUE('{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}','$.data.email' ) as test
```

You can teste the code above [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/8512)

Answer (score 3):

With v2014 there is no JSON support, but - if your real JSON is that simple - it is sometimes a good idea to use some replacements in order to transform the JSON to XML like here, which allows for the native XML methods:

```
DECLARE @YourJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'[{"data":{"email":"test@email.com"}}]';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourJSON,'[{"','<'),'":{"',' '),'":"','="'),'}}]',' />') AS XML).value('(/data/@email)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

Comment: All these replaces makes a cumbersome solution but well worth it to be able to use SQL Server's powerful built in XML support (Hopefully Json support will get a boost to match it soon)

Comment: @ZoharPeled So true! JSON is quite mighty already, but it's lacking the *real* JSON data type (it's just a special kind of `nvarchar(max)`) and some higher support of json-path. That's the reason, why expensive parsing must be done over and over and many operations are just impossible. And true too, all these replacements are cumbersome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this (SQL Server 2016):

```
DECLARE @json_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'your_json_value'
SELECT [key],value
FROM OPENJSON(@json_string, '$.email'))
```

**UPDATE :**

```
select JSON_VALUE(@json_string, '$[0].data.email') as test
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we have discovered the OP is using 2014. the fact that the OP had `JSON_VALUE` in their attempt confused us all; as they hadn't mentioned that the above would have errored with an unknown function.

Comment: `JSON_VALUE` doesn't exist in 2014.

Comment: It was a typo. Actually I share the same solution of charindex

Comment: What is a typo? `JSON_VALUE`? `select CHARINDEX(@json_string, '$[0].data.email') as test` won't work.

Comment: My update was for 2016 didn't focus on the version mentioned in the question.

Comment: What what did you mean by *"updated the case for 2014"*?